# Apache mod_rewrite to Nginx rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess, rewrite, subdomain

I have a virtual private server with whm/cpanel. 
I have installed nginx_admin plugin. 
The plugin has created virtual host files (example.com, *.example.com and manage.example.com)

In my old apache configuration file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          Options +FollowSymLinks
          Options +Indexes
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example.com [NC]
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?page=store&storeid=%1&subdomain=$1 [P]
    </IfModule>
```

How can i configure nginx for this rewrite condition and rule?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question?

Comment: Yes I did but it was wrong and inappropriate so i deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File

```
/etc/nginx/vhosts/*.example.com
```

After that code

```
server_name *.ilanimo.com;
```

Add this code

```
if ($host ~* (.*)\.example\.com) {
    set $sub $1;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=store&storeid=$sub&subdomain=$1 break;
}
```

Restart nginx

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```